# 2 out of 3 buttons on wine fridge display stopped working

Tags: button

I have an Ansonic wine fridge. It has a front display that display the temperature of the fridge, and has 3 buttons: + temperature, - temperature, and light.

[image: Button panel - outside]

Recently, the + button stopped working, so I removed the button panel and reseated it, and now the - button no longer works, but the light button still works.

On the inside, it looks like this:

[image: Button panel - inside]

Since the temperature can't be controlled anymore, it always tries to go to 10 degrees Celsius, which means the compressor is always engaged and it's too loud (it's also not the best temperature for the wine).

My question is: what kind of buttons are these, why are two of them not working anymore, and what's the best way to go about diagnosing this?

I have a multi-meter and a soldering iron, if that's helpful.

Comment: they appear to be capacitive touch buttons unless you can feel the click in which case the other wire (probably ground) of buttons is at the front panel which contacts them, try extending springs a little bit and seat them properly

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say you got a ESD  discharge (static electricity) sometime in the past when pushing a button.  I believe you fried the sensing IC. If that is true you need to replace it or get a new module. Of course you could also make your own controller.

Comment: @Gil What do you mean by module? The whole circuit board? What is a sensing IC? Is it the button or something the button connects to?

Comment: Yes I would define the circuit board as either a module or subassembly. Try contacting the manufacturer for a schematic and replacement cost.

Answer (score 1):

One issue to look for might be loose or broken connections along the switch circuit. If this cooler's control/display system is mounted on the door then it gets a lot of vibration each time the door is closed (or slammed). Over time the solder joints and/or mechanical contacts might fatigue or loosen. Contamination could also be a factor, (have you ever spilled wine on the front panel?)

From the picture it looks as though the metal springs are used to bring the capacitive signal from the outer front surface to the inner control circuitry. The larger flat disk likely gives a wide surface area to better detect a finger pressed up against the front surface.

With the power to the unit unplugged, look closely at both ends of the metal springs.  At the PCB side (solder side) verify that each spring has a solid electrical contact. If the contact is only mechanical check if the contacting surfaces have become loose, tarnished, or contaminated. Clean or tighten as needed. If the contact is a solder joint you might look for cracks.  You could even try to resolder the joint just to make sure. On the larger pad side check if there is a weak mechanical connection. Long term thermal cycling or moisture could also degrade the contact. If it has a soldered connection check for a broken solder joint. If the inner surface of the front panel has contacts these might be contaminated, you might clean this with a cotton swab with alcohol. A capacitive switch usually has a high impedance, so just a slight amount of contamination could cause a short and disable the switch.

Also while looking at the PCB look for any contamination of the PCB itself. Just as the switch contacts are high impedance some of the PCB traces going to the controller chip would be susceptible to high impedance shorts. You might clean any possible contamination with a stiff brush and alcohol, or a circuit cleaner spray.

Comment: Even if these are not capacitive switches most of the above still applies. Do the buttons indent when pressed?  If there is a grid pattern on the back surface of the panel buttons you might have a simple contact switch, (in which case there might be additional signal connections going to the front panel). Contamination and broken contacts are still a possible issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and report back.